# All hosts in MAMP Pro installation serving same host/root, even if that one is disabled?

Tags: hosts, mamp-pro, virtual-hosts

I have 8 virtual hosts set up in MAMP Pro. Only one do I use on a daily basis. Today I tried to set up a new one and discovered that it, and other hosts I have previously used without a problem, is not serving the content from the correctly specified root directory for that host, but rather it is serving up the one host I do use daily. So visiting http://thesiteiwant.dev shows me the site that should only show for http://thesitethatwontstopdisplaying.dev.

Even if I disable thesitethatwontstopdisplaying.dev with the checkbox on the Hosts screen, http://thesiteiwant.dev shows me the site that should only be associated with thesitethatwontstopdisplaying.dev (while http://thesitethatwontstopdisplaying.dev does give me the browser "server not found" error as you would expect for a disabled site).

What is happening here? Why are all 8 hosts serving me the same site, when each has a properly configured root folder for its own site? I have wasted so much time today trying to figure this out and I can't even find anyone else on the internet who has had this problem. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have redirects set up on them do you?

Comment: Nope. I haven't done much at all with the other sites in a couple months, but they've worked just fine in the past.